# Why two favicons in facebook

Tags: firefox, browser, favicon

Today when I logged into facebook, I saw two favicons in address bar near to the identity portion (I don't know exact name of this part. If somebody know, just edit my question) like the screenshot below;

[image]

But there is only one favicon in the login page;

[image]

Why is this so? What will be the possible reason? I use Firefox 13.0 in Windows 7.

Comment: You are supposed to ask this kind of questions on http://superuser.com/

Comment: @Salaros I am looking for a developer lever answer, and has definitely relaion with programming and that is why no firefox or windows-7 tag

Comment: It has nothing to do with programming, especially not with developing for Facebook. Basically your question boils down to, “Why is my browser behaving this way?”, and that’s definitively not a question for this section on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The squared area is SSL certificate information. SSL certificate contains company information (Facebook), I suppose that Firefox retrieves favicon from the company's website address, in this case facebook.com).

P.S. it doesn't matter what "level" of answer you want to receive, each kind of question belongs to its particular domain.
Moderators: please move this question as well as my answer if its possible to superuser.com

[image]